# merging multiple arrays using boost::join

Tags: c++, arrays, boost

Is it a better idea to use boost::join to access and change the values of different arrays?

I have defined a member array inside class `element`.

```
class element
{
public:
     element();
     int* get_arr();
private:
     int m_arr[4];   

}
```

At different place, I'm accessing these arrays and joined together using boost::join and changing the array values.

```
 //std::vector<element> elem;
 auto temp1 = boost::join(elem[0].get_arr(),elem[1].get_arr());
 auto joined_arr = boost::join(temp1,elem[2].get_arr()); 

//now going to change the values of the sub array
for(auto& it:joined_arr)
{
     it+=  sample[i];
      i++;
}
```

Is this a good idea to modify the values of array in the class as above?

Comment: `boost::join(elem[0].get_arr(),elem[1].get_arr())` -- this can't work because you don't join arrays but just pointers. At the location of the function call, the compiler has no information about the size of the arrays, to which the pointers point to!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you probably want to join the 4-elements arrays. To do that change the signature of `get_arr` to:

```
typedef int array[4];
array& get_arr() { return m_arr; }
```

So that the array size does not get lost.

Performance-wise there is a non-zero cost for accessing elements through the joined view. A double for loop is going to be most efficient, and easily readable too, e.g.:

```
for(auto& e : elem)
    for(auto& a : e.get_arr())
        a += sample[i++];
```

Comment: True. I think the OP is really looking for more elegance. I suspect my answer might hit the spot - looks like he's just concatening output buffers

Answer (score 2):

`boost::join` returns a more complicated type every composition step. At some point you might exceed the compiler's limits on inlining so that you're going to have a runtime cost¹.

Thinking outside the box, it really looks like you are creating a buffer abstraction that allows you to do scatter/gather like IO with few allocations.

> As it happens, Boost Asio has nice abstractions for this², and you could use that: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/MutableBufferSequence.html
>
> As I found out in an [earlier iteration of this answer code](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/48810187/2) that abstraction sadly only works for buffers accessed through native char-type elements. That was no good.

So, in this rewrite I present a similar abstraction, which consists of nothing than an "hierarchical iterator" that knows how to iterate a sequence of "buffers" (in this implementation, any range will do).

You can choose to operate on a sequence of ranges directly, e.g.:

```
std::vector<element> seq(3); // tie 3 elements together as buffer sequence
element& b = seq[1];
```

Or, without any further change, by reference:

```
element a, b, c;
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<element> > seq {a,b,c}; // tie 3 elements together as buffer sequence
```

> *The C++ version presented at the bottom demonstrates this approach <kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f370ee7b2256b617)</kbd>*

### The Iterator Implementation

I've used Boost Range and Boost Iterator:

```
template <typename Seq,
         typename WR = typename Seq::value_type,
         typename R = typename detail::unwrap<WR>::type,
         typename V = typename boost::range_value<R>::type
     >
struct sequence_iterator : boost::iterator_facade<sequence_iterator<Seq,WR,R,V>, V, boost::forward_traversal_tag> {
    using OuterIt = typename boost::range_iterator<Seq>::type;
    using InnerIt = typename boost::range_iterator<R>::type;

    // state
    Seq& _seq;
    OuterIt _ocur, _oend;
    InnerIt _icur, _iend;

    static sequence_iterator begin(Seq& seq) { return {seq, boost::begin(seq), boost::end(seq)}; }
    static sequence_iterator end(Seq&   seq) { return {seq, boost::end(seq),   boost::end(seq)}; }

    // the 3 facade operations
    bool equal(sequence_iterator const& rhs) const {
        return ((_ocur==_oend) && (rhs._ocur==rhs._oend))
            || (std::addressof(_seq) == std::addressof(rhs._seq) &&
                _ocur == rhs._ocur && _oend == rhs._oend &&
                _icur == rhs._icur && _iend == rhs._iend);
    }

    void increment() {
        if (++_icur == _iend) {
            ++_ocur;
            setup();
        }
    }

    V& dereference() const {
        assert(_ocur != _oend);
        assert(_icur != _iend);
        return *_icur;
    }

  private:
    void setup() { // to be called after entering a new sub-range in the sequence
        while (_ocur != _oend) {
            _icur = boost::begin(detail::get(*_ocur));
            _iend = boost::end(detail::get(*_ocur));

            if (_icur != _iend)
                break;
            ++_ocur; // skid over, this enables simple increment() logic
        }
    }

    sequence_iterator(Seq& seq, OuterIt cur, OuterIt end)
        : _seq(seq), _ocur(cur), _oend(end) { setup(); }
};
```

That's basically the same kind of iterator as `boost::asio::buffers_iterator` but it doesn't assume an element type. Now, creating `sequence_iterator`s for any sequence of ranges is as simple as:

```
template <typename Seq> auto buffers_begin(Seq& seq) { return sequence_iterator<Seq>::begin(seq); }
template <typename Seq> auto buffers_end(Seq& seq)   { return sequence_iterator<Seq>::end(seq); }
```

### Implementing Your Test Program

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fdbb000f64533eb1)</kbd>**

```
// DEMO
struct element {
    int peek_first() const { return m_arr[0]; }

    auto begin() const { return std::begin(m_arr); } 
    auto end() const   { return std::end(m_arr);   } 
    auto begin()       { return std::begin(m_arr); } 
    auto end()         { return std::end(m_arr);   } 

  private:
    int m_arr[4] { };
};

namespace boost { // range adapt
    template <> struct range_iterator<element> { using type = int*; };
    // not used, but for completeness:
    template <> struct range_iterator<element const> { using type = int const*; };
    template <> struct range_const_iterator<element> : range_iterator<element const> {};
}

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename Output, typename Input, typename Operation>
size_t process(Output& output, Input const& input, Operation op) {
    auto ib = boost::begin(input), ie = boost::end(input);
    auto ob = boost::begin(output), oe = boost::end(output);

    size_t n = 0;
    for (;ib!=ie && ob!=oe; ++n) {
        op(*ob++, *ib++);
    }
    return n;
}

int main() {
    element a, b, c;
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<element> > seq {a,b,c}; // tie 3 elements together as buffer sequence

    //// Also supported, container of range objects directly:
    // std::list<element> seq(3); // tie 3 elements together as buffer sequence
    // element& b = seq[1];

    std::vector<int> const samples { 
         1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12,
        13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24,
        25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32
    };

    using boost::make_iterator_range;
    auto input  = make_iterator_range(samples);
    auto output = make_iterator_range(buffers_begin(seq), buffers_end(seq));

    while (auto n = process(output, input, [](int& el, int sample) { el += sample; })) {
        std::cout << "Copied " << n << " samples, b starts with " << b.peek_first() << "\n";
        input.advance_begin(n);
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Copied 12 samples, b starts with 5
Copied 12 samples, b starts with 22
Copied 8 samples, b starts with 51
```

### Full Listing, C++11 Compatible

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f370ee7b2256b617)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>
#include <functional> // std::reference_wrapper

namespace detail {
    template<typename T> constexpr T&       get(T &t)                         { return t;  } 
    template<typename T> constexpr T const& get(T const &t)                   { return t;  } 
    template<typename T> constexpr T&       get(std::reference_wrapper<T> rt) { return rt; } 

    template <typename T> struct unwrap { using type = T; };
    template <typename T> struct unwrap<std::reference_wrapper<T> > { using type = T; };
}

template <typename Seq,
         typename WR = typename Seq::value_type,
         typename R = typename detail::unwrap<WR>::type,
         typename V = typename boost::range_value<R>::type
     >
struct sequence_iterator : boost::iterator_facade<sequence_iterator<Seq,WR,R,V>, V, boost::forward_traversal_tag> {
    using OuterIt = typename boost::range_iterator<Seq>::type;
    using InnerIt = typename boost::range_iterator<R>::type;

    // state
    Seq& _seq;
    OuterIt _ocur, _oend;
    InnerIt _icur, _iend;

    static sequence_iterator begin(Seq& seq) { return {seq, boost::begin(seq), boost::end(seq)}; }
    static sequence_iterator end(Seq&   seq) { return {seq, boost::end(seq),   boost::end(seq)}; }

    // the 3 facade operations
    bool equal(sequence_iterator const& rhs) const {
        return ((_ocur==_oend) && (rhs._ocur==rhs._oend))
            || (std::addressof(_seq) == std::addressof(rhs._seq) &&
                _ocur == rhs._ocur && _oend == rhs._oend &&
                _icur == rhs._icur && _iend == rhs._iend);
    }

    void increment() {
        if (++_icur == _iend) {
            ++_ocur;
            setup();
        }
    }

    V& dereference() const {
        assert(_ocur != _oend);
        assert(_icur != _iend);
        return *_icur;
    }

  private:
    void setup() { // to be called after entering a new sub-range in the sequence
        while (_ocur != _oend) {
            _icur = boost::begin(detail::get(*_ocur));
            _iend = boost::end(detail::get(*_ocur));

            if (_icur != _iend)
                break;
            ++_ocur; // skid over, this enables simple increment() logic
        }
    }

    sequence_iterator(Seq& seq, OuterIt cur, OuterIt end)
        : _seq(seq), _ocur(cur), _oend(end) { setup(); }
};

template <typename Seq> auto buffers_begin(Seq& seq) { return sequence_iterator<Seq>::begin(seq); }
template <typename Seq> auto buffers_end(Seq& seq)   { return sequence_iterator<Seq>::end(seq); }

// DEMO
struct element {
    int peek_first() const { return m_arr[0]; }

    auto begin() const { return std::begin(m_arr); } 
    auto end() const   { return std::end(m_arr);   } 
    auto begin()       { return std::begin(m_arr); } 
    auto end()         { return std::end(m_arr);   } 

  private:
    int m_arr[4] { };
};

namespace boost { // range adapt
    template <> struct range_iterator<element> { using type = int*; };
    // not used, but for completeness:
    template <> struct range_iterator<element const> { using type = int const*; };
    template <> struct range_const_iterator<element> : range_iterator<element const> {};
}

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename Output, typename Input, typename Operation>
size_t process(Output& output, Input const& input, Operation op) {
    auto ib = boost::begin(input), ie = boost::end(input);
    auto ob = boost::begin(output), oe = boost::end(output);

    size_t n = 0;
    for (;ib!=ie && ob!=oe; ++n) {
        op(*ob++, *ib++);
    }
    return n;
}

int main() {
    element a, b, c;
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<element> > seq {a,b,c}; // tie 3 elements together as buffer sequence

    //// Also supported, container of range objects directly:
    // std::list<element> seq(3); // tie 3 elements together as buffer sequence
    // element& b = seq[1];

    std::vector<int> const samples { 
         1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12,
        13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24,
        25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32
    };

    using boost::make_iterator_range;
    auto input  = make_iterator_range(samples);
    auto output = make_iterator_range(buffers_begin(seq), buffers_end(seq));

    while (auto n = process(output, input, [](int& el, int sample) { el += sample; })) {
        std::cout << "Copied " << n << " samples, b starts with " << b.peek_first() << "\n";
        input.advance_begin(n);
    }
}
```

---

¹ I'm ignoring the compile-time cost and the lurking dangers with the pattern of `auto x = complicated_range_composition` when that complicated range composition contains references to temporaries: this is a frequent source of [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) bugs

² which have been adopted by various other libraries, like Boost Beast, Boost Process and seem to have found their way into the Networking TS for C++20: [Header `<experimental/buffer>` synopsis (PDF)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4711.pdf)

Comment: The original problem is adding samples to array elements. This solution seems to be doing a copy. Is that right?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I've replaced my answer with one that... actually works. It's basically the same idea, instead of using Asio's because it turns out not well-suited for non-character buffers. I learned a lot again, today.

Comment: You mentioned that _OP is really looking for more elegance_. Do you think if you add more code your solution is going to be even more elegant?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin No, I think this is pretty much the sweet spot. It's all about using the right level of abstractions. Note that I did try existing implementations first. I would probably not have answered the question at all had I not been aware of those.

Comment: So, to spell it out, if this is the only time the OP requires it, it's silly to write all that code. But the OP was clearly not asking for guidance on how to rite the loops. Peace

Comment: Dear @sehe, I value your answers and am subscribed to your feed. Regarding this particular question, I do not think your solution is anywhere near to being elegant. The mathematical definition of elegance is simplicity and power. Your solution lacks these qualities. It introduces a few levels of abstraction/indirection, it makes it harder to read and understand, and exhibits sub-optimal performance. Rather than being elegant, it matches most the definition of over-engineered.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Whenever you look at the implementation of library features, you will have that exact same feeling. I answered a question with building an abstraction. You think that's a bad thing, I happen to think it is highly valuable to show people how to do that. Again, if it's just the one occurrence, it's silly to write this amount of code. But if you use this kind of data structure throughout your code, it will repay itself in reduced complexity.

Comment: Part of the ugliness in my sample  (big part, actually) ends up being due to STL algorithms not being flexible enough (`std::copy` and `std::transform` can't deal with destination ranges of smaller size than input range). One could say "oh well, back to handwriting algorithms" or one can build the missing abstraction (in this case `process`). [Look at this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f47279451a234fe7) and say it's inelegant: (If you do, that's fine)

Comment: (Thanks for the kind words, by the way. Out of curiosity, what's your opinion on Boost in general? I'm asking because I personally [find it frequently  over-engineered](https://twitter.com/sehetw/status/917372564615450624)).

Comment: I value Boost greatly. In 2001 I systematically read entire boost source code a-to-z and I learned a lot from it. Contributed to a few boost libraries.

Comment: _Beauty is more important in computing than anywhere else in technology because software is so complicated. Beauty is the ultimate defense against complexity._ - from [The Art of Unix Programming](http://www.catb.org/esr/writings/taoup/html/transparencychapter.html), you may like the entire chapter.

Comment: My most used boost libraries when using C++11 are accumulatros, fusion, dynamic-bitset, filesystem, date-time, multi-index, intrusive, intrusive_ptr, iostreams, iterator, lexical_cast, mpl, preprocessor, python, range, regex, serialization, string-algo, test, ublas.

Comment: Looking forward to using Asio.